# Crash on sleep after running eclipse with ADT plugin installed

Tags: android, adb, windows-7-x64

I've been having issues for a while where my Windows 7 machine would blue-screen when I tried to put it to sleep. I ignored the issue and just avoided using sleep until I recently happened to figure out that the crash occurred only after I'd run Eclipse. By comparing with a fresh install and adding plugins individually, I was able to source the problem to the Android Development Tools plugin for Eclipse. If I run a fresh version of Eclipse with the Android plugin installed, then the next time I tell the machine to sleep it shows a blue screen instead. If I specifically remove the com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.jar from the plugins directory, then the crash does not occur, although I of course lose the functionality of the plugin.

Now I'm at a loss. I can tell whats causing the problem but I have no idea how I can fix it if I want to continue to use the Android plugins in Eclipse. Does anyone have any advice on how to further troubleshoot this?

Edit: After reinstalling drivers, the crash appears to occur under the following specific condition: The old Motorola Droid II that I use as a backup testing device has USB drivers installed and is plugged in, and adb.exe is running (either while eclipse is running or after it has closed). Knowing that, I have the easy workarounds of unplugging the device or stopping the adb.exe process before putting the computer to sleep. Still no idea why there's a crash under those conditions, though.

Edit2: Since this hasn't been touched in a while, worth noting that it's an adb issue and not an eclipse issue (it occurs using Android Studio as well), so I've updated tags accordingly.

Comment: Can you try to reinstall the driver for your Android device?

Comment: Reinstalling drivers doesn't make the problem go away, but it did help me isolate where the problem takes place. Will update post with details.

Comment: I have this same issue with HTC and Motorola phones. Sleeping with them connected to ADB (newest) causes Win 7 x64 Pro to blue screen. This is a 100% reproducible issue on both my workstations.

Comment: @Cory Haven't tried to attack this issue in quite a while, but I updated the tags to include adb since that seems to be the root cause, so we'll see if that turns anything up.